# Как сделать , чтобы в конструктор класса в Python __init__ попадали только нужные типы данных

Tags: python, ооп, классы, конструктор, init

Изучая ООП в языке программирования Python, у меня появился вопрос, ответ на который я не смог найти.
В Python есть конкструктор класса `__init__` , который позволяет нам сказать , что для создания класса нам нужны какие-то параметры, также есть геттеры и сеттеры, которые помогают нам в инкапсуляции.
Так вот в чём заключается мой вопрос: Сеттеры - помогают нам защитить свойства от недопустимых изменений , допустим если в переменную введут отрицательное число или вовсе не от тип данных. НО как избежать того , чтобы эти самые неправильные параметры не передали в конструктор класса , допустим не передали отрицательное число или тип `str` вместо `int`?

```
class Persone:
def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.__name = name
    self.__age = age
tom = Persone ("Tom","22")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во первых можно бросить исключение:

```
class Persone:
    def __init__(self,name, age):
        if type(age) != int:
            raise Exception("не тот тип")

        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
```

во-вторых можно если не те данные выставлять данные по умолчанию:

```
class Persone:
    def __init__(self,name, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = 0 if type(age) != int else age
```

можно конечно тип указывать явно, но вроде это ни на что не влияет (могу ошибаться):

```
class Persone:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
```

Comment: тайпинг влияет только на автодополнение кода в редакторе и подсвечивается линтером

Answer (score 0):

```
class FatalError(Exception):
    def __init__(self,  description):
        super().__init__(description)


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        if isinstance(age, int) is False:
            raise FatalError("Программа аварийно завершила свою работу из-за фатальной ошибки!")
        else:
            self.__age = age
        self.__name = name
        

def main():
    person_alexandro = Person("Alexandro", "38")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "Программа завершила свою работу из-за фатальной ошибки!" =)_)

Comment: Да про данные по умолчанию, забыл как то :-)